# Sorting from Alphanumeric to nonAlphnumeric

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a array of data:

```
!
A
B
E
$
N
```

I'd like it to be sorted from Alphanumeric to Non-Alphanumeric.

Example:  `A B E N ! $`

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a customized sorting order, you need to provide your own comparison function. In your case (letters+digits first, the rest later), you can use something like

```
var data = "!ABE$N".ToCharArray().ToList();
data.Sort((x, y) => {
    if (x == y) return 0;
    if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(x))
    {
        if (!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(y)) return -1;
        return x < y ? -1 : +1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(y)) return +1;
        return x < y ? -1 : +1;
    }
});
```

**Added** per comment: The same thing, only with a different syntax (using a plain-old named method):

```
int MyComparisonFunction(char x, char y)
{
    if (x == y) return 0;
    if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(x))
    {
        if (!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(y)) return -1;
        return x < y ? -1 : +1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(y)) return +1;
        return x < y ? -1 : +1;
    }
}

// ...

var data = "!ABE$N".ToCharArray().ToList();
data.Sort(MyComparisonFunction);
```

The same thing in still another style would be to create an [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) implementation and use that. That is useful if the sorting order should be used on more places, many collections and controls offer an IComparer property to override the sorting order:

```
public class AlphabeticPriorToNonalphabeticComparer : IComparer<char>
{
    public int Compare(char x, char y)
    {
        if (x == y) return 0;
        if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(x))
        {
            if (!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(y)) return -1;
            return x < y ? -1 : +1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(y)) return +1;
            return x < y ? -1 : +1;
        }
    }
}
// ...
var data = "!ABE$N".ToCharArray().ToList();
var myComparer = new AlphabeticPriorToNonalphabeticComparer();
data.Sort(myComparer);
```

Comment: The whole construction is an anonymous function providing a [comparison method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) for the sort. `x` and `y` are just arguments to the comparison (values being compared, in your case, two characters), like arguments to any other method, only in this case, [lambda expression syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) was used. I’ll add alternate syntax to be clear.

Comment: Beautiful! I was able to add this right to my ICompare for UltraGrid. YOU ROCK!

Answer (score 3):

```
char[] yourOriginalValues = new [] { '!', 'A', 'B', 'E', '$', 'N' };

IEnumerable<char> result = 
       yourOriginalValues.Where(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
            .OrderBy(c => c)
            .Concat(yourOriginalValues.Where(c => !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)));
```

That seems to yield the values you're looking for.

Comment: Note that this will keep the nonalphabetic characters _in the original order_, e.g. `!ABE$N` and `$ABE!N` will have different results (`ABEN!$` and `ABEN$!`, respectively). This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: One last question, I'm using WinUltraGrid, how would I go about adding this to sort like this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have absolutely no idea; I've never used WinUltraGrid, or even heard of it.  Just ask a new question, and someone else will likely be able to help you out.

Comment: @Wesley, note that @Mormegil's comment is correct.  If you want the non-alpha-non-number characters sorted in a specific order, tack on an OrderBy right after:  yourOriginalValues.Where(c => !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with a combination of the [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) and [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx) extension methods:

```
char[] data = { 'E', 'B', '$', 'N', '!', 'A' };
var query = data.OrderByDescending(c => char.IsLetter(c))
                .ThenBy(c => c);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray.Sort();
```

That will use the default, alphabetic (non numeric) sort. That should work or am I missing something?

Comment: myArray.Sort(); will place the Non-alphanumeric characters in front, thus not what I want.